# Expired Page While Submitting payment

Tags: vb.net, caching

I am currently writing a bot to submit payments on a certain site. I wrote it all with simple form; grabs and fill works just fine, but the issue is when it goes through the first submit payment the web browser shows web page expired. I need help so that I do not get a webpage expired when I go forward into the payment.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Security.Policy

Public Class Form1

    Dim test As String
    Dim useless As String
    Dim usernme As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim first() As String
    Dim fullname As String
    Dim firstn As String
    Dim lastn As String
    Dim email As String
    Dim full As String
    Dim fulldir() As String
    Dim stszip() As String
    Dim adress As String
    Dim city As String
    Dim state As String
    Dim zip As String
#Region "Page Loading Functions"
    Private Property pageready As Boolean = False


    Private Sub WaitForPageLoad()
        AddHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
        While Not pageready
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        pageready = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub PageWaiter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        If WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
            pageready = True
            RemoveHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
        End If
    End Sub

#End Region
#Region "Page Loading Functions 2"
    Private Property pageready2 As Boolean = False


    Private Sub WaitForPageLoad2()
        AddHandler WebBrowser2.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter2)
        While Not pageready
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        pageready = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub PageWaiter2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        If WebBrowser2.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
            pageready = True
            RemoveHandler WebBrowser2.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter2)
        End If
    End Sub

#End Region

    Dim url As String = ""
    Dim pass As String

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow
        e.Cancel = True
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(WebBrowser1.StatusText)
    End Sub
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

        Dim links As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.Links
        For Each var As HtmlElement In links
            var.AttachEventHandler("onclick", AddressOf LinkClicked)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim link As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
        url = link.GetAttribute("href")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        WebBrowser2.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
        WebBrowser2.Navigate("http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/")
        WaitForPageLoad2()
        Dim docum As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        Dim i As Integer = -1
        For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In docum
            If CurElement.GetAttribute("classname") = "address" Then
                full = CurElement.InnerText
                RichTextBox1.Text = full
            End If
        Next
        docum = WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")
        For Each CurElement2 As HtmlElement In docum
            If CurElement2.GetAttribute("classname") = "value" Then
                test = CurElement2.InnerText
                If test.Contains("@") Then
                    email = test
                End If
            End If
        Next
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + vbCrLf + email
        fullname = RichTextBox1.Lines(0).ToString
        first = Split(fullname, ".")
        firstn = first(0)
        lastn = first(1)
        fulldir = Split(RichTextBox1.Lines(2).ToString, ",")
        city = fulldir(0)
        useless = fulldir(1)
        stszip = Split(useless, " ")
        state = stszip(1)
        zip = stszip(2)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", email)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", pass)
        Dim subm1 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each subm2 As HtmlElement In subm1
            If subm2.GetAttribute("type") = "submit" Then
                subm2.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
        WaitForPageLoad()
        MsgBox("lol")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("first-name").SetAttribute("value", firstn)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("last-name").SetAttribute("value", lastn)
        Dim zipcodchk As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each zipcodch As HtmlElement In zipcodchk
            If zipcodch.GetAttribute("id") = "zip_code" Then
                zipcodch.SetAttribute("value", zip)
            End If
        Next
        For Each country As HtmlElement In zipcodchk
            If country.GetAttribute("id") = "fake_country" Then
                country.SetAttribute("value", "US")
            End If
        Next
        Dim fullcc() As String
        fullcc = Split(TextBox1.Text, "|")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ccn").SetAttribute("value", fullcc(0))
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("month").SetAttribute("value", fullcc(1))
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("year").SetAttribute("value", fullcc(2))
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("cvv2_code").SetAttribute("value", fullcc(3))
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("continue3").InvokeMember("click")
        WaitForPageLoad()
        Dim subm3 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each subm4 As HtmlElement In subm3
            If subm4.GetAttribute("id") = "continue3" Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("572").InvokeMember("click")
        WaitForPageLoad()
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("without-donation").InvokeMember("click")
        WaitForPageLoad()
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("checkbox1").InvokeMember("click")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("checkbox1").SetAttribute("value", "No")
        Dim submit3 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each pressed As HtmlElement In submit3
            If pressed.GetAttribute("type") = "submit" Then
                pressed.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
        WaitForPageLoad()
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("continue-receipt").InvokeMember("click")
        WaitForPageLoad()
        If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString.Contains("home") Then
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text + 1
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub GenerateString()

        Dim xCharArray() As Char = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray
        Dim xNoArray() As Char = "0123456789".ToCharArray
        Dim xGenerator As System.Random = New System.Random()
        Dim xStr As String = String.Empty

        While xStr.Length < 8

            If xGenerator.Next(0, 2) = 0 Then
                xStr &= xCharArray(xGenerator.Next(0, xCharArray.Length))
            Else
                xStr &= xNoArray(xGenerator.Next(0, xNoArray.Length))
            End If

        End While
        pass = xStr
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("first-name").SetAttribute("value", firstn)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("last-name").SetAttribute("value", lastn)
        Dim zipcodchk As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each zipcodch As HtmlElement In zipcodchk
            If zipcodch.GetAttribute("id") = "zip_code" Then
                zipcodch.SetAttribute("value", zip)
            End If
        Next
        Dim fullcc() As String
        fullcc = Split(TextBox1.Text, "|")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ccn").SetAttribute("value", fullcc(0))
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("month").SetAttribute("value", fullcc(1))
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("year").SetAttribute("value", fullcc(2))
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("cvv2_code").SetAttribute("value", fullcc(3))
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("continue3").InvokeMember("click")
        WaitForPageLoad()
        Dim subm3 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each subm4 As HtmlElement In subm3
            If subm4.GetAttribute("id") = "continue3" Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("572").InvokeMember("click")
        WaitForPageLoad()
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("without-donation").InvokeMember("click")
        WaitForPageLoad()
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("checkbox1").InvokeMember("click")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("checkbox1").SetAttribute("value", "No")
        Dim submit3 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each pressed As HtmlElement In submit3
            If pressed.GetAttribute("type") = "submit" Then
                pressed.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
        WaitForPageLoad()
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("continue-receipt").InvokeMember("click")
        WaitForPageLoad()
        If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString.Contains("home") Then
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text + 1
        End If
    End Sub
```

I left out the site im working on if it is the site then there is nothing i can do

Comment: it is the site as session is defined on the web server. One thought is to do this in batches. Process for x minutes. Disconnect wait a bit, reconnect, process for X minutes, etc...

Comment: so it is the site ? i just don't understand why it would be so even when i do it manually inside vb.ne web browser it still gives me that error but what your saying is that theres nothing i can do ?

Comment: i saw some ppl talking about getting rid of this error with asp.net so i thought maybe there would  be a way for me to do some on vb.net